# Correction of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct ?

> The sufferings of the ethnic group dates back to the colonial rule .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example

> The sufferings of the ethnic group dates back to **the** colonial rule.

sounds incomplete, you would usually use "***the***" if you were to mention a specific "***colonial rule***"

> The sufferings of the ethnic group dates back to **the** colonial rule *of the English*.

Otherwise, one might use

> The sufferings of the ethnic group dates back to colonial rule.

to refer to the time/era of "***colonial rule***" in general.

Comment: That means the phrase   $\dates back to$ matches with it ...@Peter , thank you...